# User-defined function program in python is not working

Tags: python-2.7, user-defined-functions

I have written this code in python which is working but when I tried to write that same program by using functions it's impossible. Help me!
This is the code which is working :

```
count=0
total=0   
while True:
    try:
        itervar=raw_input('Enter a number: ')
        if  itervar == 'done':
            break
        itervar=float(itervar)
        count=count+1
        total=total+itervar
        average=total/count
    except:
        print 'Invalid input'
print total, ' ' , count, ' ' , average
```

This is not working :

```
def count(itervar):
    count = count+1
    return count

def total(itervar):
    total = total+itervar
    return total

def average(count,total):
    z=total/count
    return z
count=0
total=0
while True:
    try:
        itervar=raw_input('Enter a number: ')
        if  itervar == 'done':
            break
        itervar=float(itervar)
        count=count(itervar)
        total=total(itervar)

    except:
        print 'Invalid input'
print total, ' ' , count, ' ' , average(count,total)
```

Comment: I think you'll want to pass variable to `count()` and `total()` and set them up to receive the same.

Comment: Also, `count1` and `total1` aren't defined before they are used.

Comment: I tried it when I am passing itervar in count() and total(), even numeric values are 'Invalid input' it means code is jumping to except:

Comment: That's my mistake count1 and total1 are count and total. :)

Comment: Can you revise the code in your question with what you have now?

Comment: Done! Please check again.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a good idea to name your variables the same as your function name. I cleaned that up here:

```
def count(this_count):
    return this_count + 1

def total(this_itervar, this_total):
    return this_itervar + this_total

def avg(this_count, this_total):
    if this_count == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return this_total /this_count

this_count=0
this_total=0
while True:
    try:
        itervar=raw_input('Enter a number: ')
        if  itervar == 'done':
            break
        itervar=float(itervar)
        this_count = count(this_count)
        this_total = total(itervar, this_total)

    except:
        print 'Invalid input'
print str(this_total) + ' ' + str(this_count) + ' ' + str(avg(this_count, this_total))
```

Comment: Thank You very much. average() is having an error (Dividing by zero error) It's the last problem I guess. :)

Comment: Try this new function. I believe `average` may be a reserved word, so I changed it to `avg`.

Comment: I had some errors in the last bit of code. Please try my edits.

Comment: Thank You very much everything works just fine now. :)

Comment: Good to hear. All the best in your future coding.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just noticed that in avg() You divided count from total. :D Again thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry, yes, need to reverse the two. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Can you suggest me some fields related to python which i can pursue, which will be more in demand in companies. Like what's next after learning how to code in python.

Comment: I use python for web development. I would suggest learning django next. It is written in python and works well with it for web development. All the best.